# Echo shell log while entering and then exit

Tags: shell, centos, output

While I type a command, this command will authenticate with a remote server and do a bunch of things. If pass, it will give me a bash shell with its environment.

My goal is to save these log which prints out into my terminal for future inspection. Let's say my command called `target`.

While I type target, it throws the following msg.

```
Version:        V1.94
Options:
Date:           Thu Jun  6 17:18:39 2019
OS:             CentOS release 6.10 (Final)
....
[DEV]target>
```

Notice the last line implied I've entered the target shell environment.

I've tried `echo $(target) > output.log`, but it will be stuck until I type `CTRL+C`.

Environment: CentOS 6.10

### Update

Let's say I want to make this script automatically run when I activate my machine. However, it will still be stuck while executing the target command because it entered a shell and didn't leave.

```
#!/bin/bash
script -c target output.log
FILENAMEME=output.log
aws s3 cp "$FILENAME" s3://logs/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try `script`:

```
script -c target output.log
```

This would start the command `target` and save a transcript of the whole session, until `target` terminates, into the file `output.log`.  If the command (your `target`) is several words long, quote the full command.

See the manual for `script` (`man script`).

Comment: Thanks, but is it possible to send `terminates` command after the target command? Since I need to send output.log to somewhere after that

Comment: @CodaChang I'm not sure I understand what you mean. The `script` command will finish when your `target` command finishes, i.e. when you log out of the remote machine.

Comment: Hi, I had updated my questions. It should give you a better way to understand. Thanks

Comment: @CodaChang It is not clear when you consider the transcript file (`output.log`) to be done.

Comment: It's quite hard to define whether it's done or not since it needs to connect with the remote server. Can I state 1 min timeout and exit it?

Comment: @CodaChang If you have the `timeout` utility, you could just prefix the whole command with `timeout 1m`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I can make a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't change the `target` command itself, then this should be helpful:

```
target | tee output.bak
```

`output.bak` will contain a copy of all the output (just stdout in this example), so you'll have to trim it if you want just the initial info.